# Surface integral on unit sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling to calculate the surface integral in this question

> Find the area of the portion of the sphere $$z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$
>   Which lies between the planes $z=0$ and $z=1$

Now I know the integral takes the following form:
$$\iint_U{|N(x,y)|dxdy}$$
Now parametrising the surface with $$r(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \end{pmatrix}$$
The normal is $$N(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} -f_x\\ -f_y\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\\ \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now the integral is $$\iint_U{\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}}\;dxdy}$$
However I can't work out the bounds for the integral. I can't just plug in $z=0$ and $z=1$ as then I'll get $U$ as a flat space interval of the circle from radius $0$-$4$. And I'm pretty sure $U$ is a curved subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Does anyone have any hints to set me on the right path?

Thanks

EDIT: I need to calculate the area using a surface integral, even though its only half of a full sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us make the computation, without seeing the result as in Sabyasachi's answer, and for a general $r$.

The elementary area is, with [Mathematica notations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) in spheric coordinates:
$$
r^2\sin\phi d\phi d\theta
$$

Here $r$ is a constant and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi 2]$:

$$
A = r^2\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sin \phi d\phi\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta 
= 2\pi [-\cos\phi]_0^{\frac \pi 2}r^2 = 2\pi r^2
$$

Comment: Glad you caught it, I was about to say something . . .

Comment: Guess I'll chime in, having watched, witnessed, and participated in the dialogue over the *true area* of a unit hemisphere:  yeah, the answer is $2 \pi$, easy if you already know the total area of the sphere is $4 \pi$.  But I think the point of this exercise is to derive this result!  By integration, no less!  Here's what I would do:  Express the area element $dA$ of the sphere in spherical coordinates, as mookid has shown us.  Was about to write it up when he posted.  +1!

Comment: AH ok thanks, taking $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives you half the sphere. Makes sense

Comment: @Robert Lewis haha this was quite fun. One should always work on the classics :)

Comment: @mookid:  indeed!

Comment: @mookid very true. I learnt integration two years back, and all I was doing for a weeks was "derive every volume and area formula you know" :D nice days.

Answer (score 2):

Our (hemi)sphere is $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, so a sphere of radius $1$. Therefore the entire hemisphere lies *exactly* between $z=0$ and $z=1$. Thus the area is $2\pi r^2=2\pi$

This avoids the hassle of the integration(which admittedly I do not understand)

**EDIT**: Thanks to mookid for pointing out a hugely embarrassing mistake.

---

**EDIT 2:** Apparently cheating isn't allowed, and we need to derive the formula.

If we take a line at an angle of $\theta$ with the $x$ axis from the origin to the surface, then $r\cos(\theta)$ is the radius of the disc formed at that point with centre on the $z$ axis. This disc has perimeter $2\pi r\cos(\theta)$ and therefore the area covered by rotating the line $\operatorname{d}\theta$ is $2\pi r^2\cos(\theta)\rm{d}\theta$(multiplying length of the perimeter by $r\rm{d}\theta$). Integrating from $0$ to $\pi/2$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}2\pi r^2\cos(\theta)\rm{d}\theta = 2\pi r^2$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: isn't this an **area**?

Comment: @mookid my bad. area is $2\pi r^2$ right? changing.

Comment: I actually made the same :)

Comment: @mookid happens to all of us apparently. :p plus I really dont understand that area.(I'm only in high school never having done double or triple integrals)

Comment: Yeah I know the area is $2\pi$ however I need to use the integral to find it...

Comment: Although, to be honest, that area formula comes from integration anyway, so....

Comment: @George1811 ouch. can't help you bro. can i use the observation that this is an hemisphere then derive the formula of area of a sphere then half it?

Comment: I don't think so my previous question was finding the surface area of the full sphere via a surface integral and I don't think they'd accept me just halving it :(

Comment: @George1811: see my answer.

Comment: @George1811 did you use this proof? this is badass likewise. plus you can use any $\theta$